Error: /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
my render has been showing me 'Error: /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header' whenever i want to deploy my backend 'Node.js'
please whoever has encounter this type of error should show me how to fix it

Does this answer your question? bcrypt invalid elf header when running node app

I was also following the same problem when deploying my project backend. You can uninstall the bcrypt from your project but keep the "bcrypt": "^5.1.1" or whatever version you are using in your "dependencies": {}. Do the following steps:

Uninstall bcrypt
Add the following the line to your "dependencies": {"bcrypt": "^5.1.1"}
Now deploy your project on render.

Hopefully, this will solve the problem for you as well. If not, let me know here.
